# Configurable parent product display out of stock

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, out-of-stock

Configurable product shows out of stock whether child product still in stock. Can't figure out what to do to show in stock parent product if any child product have stock. Please help me .

Comment: I doubt you are using this extension: https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher, are you?

Comment: @Khatri Thanks for quick reply. No, not using this extension.

Comment: Can you confirm you have set `in-stock` in your config items's inventory?

Comment: Yes,in simple product & configurable product show out of stock if those product stock limit is over, $qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();  using this code get quantity of a product but how can i get child product quantity in configurable product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
//load parent product "$product"
if($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable'){
   $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                ->getUsedProducts(null,$product);

   // now get qty from collection
   $qtyModel = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
   foreach($childProducts as $key => $child){
      $childQty[$key] = $qtyModel->loadByProduct($child)->getQty();
   }
}
```

Now you can put your other logic.

Hope this helps.

**Assumption**
`$product` is a config parent product object.

Comment: It's show an error.  Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getUsedProducts() in

Comment: Have you defined `$product` before my code? Also check my edited answer.

Comment: Yes,$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
         ->getUsedProducts(null,$_product); $_product is the parent product

Comment: Hi @Khatri, thanks for your help. At last, I've got my solution using your code :) +1

Answer (score 0):

I would like to show barcode attribute value. How can I show barcode value? Thank you for your help.

```
  <?
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                 ->getUsedProducts(null,$product);
$stock_count=0;
$sizeqty="";
foreach($childProducts as $child){
 if($child->getAttributeText('ust_beden_no')!=""){   
 $sizeqty.="<Stok><isim>Beden</isim><Beden>".$child->getAttributeText('ust_beden_no')."</Beden><Miktar>".
(int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($child)->getQty()."



</Miktar></Stok>";
 

}
}
 return $sizeqty;
?>
```